# "necessary tools" or "the necessary tools"?

Tags: articles, definite-article

Tell me please if I need to include the definite article in the following sentence.

> I cannot fix the computer right now as I don't have (**the**) necessary tools for it.

I am not sure whether to use it or not because on one hand I didn't specify what tools was needed, therefore the article isn't necessary. But on the other hand it is clear what tools was needed. The ones which fit for fixing the computer, and so the article seems to be necessary. Could the use of it be optinal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word **necessary** implies that you know what is necessary. And if you know something you must specify it using the article **the**. Therefore it is better if you say--

> I cannot fix the computer right now as I don't have the necessary tools for it.